# What is the best way to find if there are any duplicates in nested child property in a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have an array of objects(Vue 3 prop) like below. The array is for `room` objects. Each room contains `adults` and `childs` array with `adult` and `child` objects. Now I need to mark the duplicate names (`first` and `last` name together) by adding a property name `error` (Shown in example).

```
[
    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "John", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"}
    ],
    "children": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Joe", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },

    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Johny", "last": "Doe",},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe",}
    ],
    "children": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Jui", "last": "Doe"}
    ]
    },
]
```

After I run the function or code in question. The resulting array should look like below.

```
[
    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "John", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." }
    ],
    "children": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." },
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Joe", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },

    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Johny", "last": "Doe", },
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." }
    ],
    "children": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." },
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Jui", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },
]
```

**Update:**

This is my first question to Stack Overflow, even though I am regular user of the platform for last 7+ years.

I am overwhelmed by the responses and definitely will go through each solution.

I am not a JS developer and tried to make a solution (inspired by
vanowm's comment) that now looks like below. I believe the responses have a better solution.

````
const isDuplicate = function (names, person) {
    let result = false;
    
    names.forEach(function (name) {
        if(name.first === person.first && name.last === person.last){
            result = true;
        }
    });
    
    return result;
}

const validateNames = function () {
    let names = [];

    rooms.forEach(function (room) {

        room.adults.forEach(function (adult) {
            if (isDuplicate(names, adult)) {
                adult.error = 'Duplicate name, please update.'
                // I can do this because it is a Vue Reactive.
            } else {
                adult.error = ''
                names.push(adult);
            }
        })
        
        room.childs.forEach(function (child) {
            if (isDuplicate(names, child)) {
                child.error = 'Duplicate name, please update.'
            } else {
                child.error = ''
                names.push(child);
            }
        })
    });
};```
````

Comment: He made a comment before posting his answer. @JaromandaX

Comment: can you clarify, are you looking for duplicates amongst all names, or just duplicates amongst adults, and amongst children separately? your only duplicate is Jane Doe ... both a Mrs and a Ms - so it's hard to ascertain what your end goal actually is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my naive attempt

I **assumed** you want to find duplicates among adults separately from duplicates among children - it's not clear since the only duplicate is Jane Doe and she appears twice as an adult and twice as a child!

```js
const data = [
    {
        RoomType: {},
        Price: {},
        Messages: [],
        CancellationPolicyStatus: "",
        adults: [
            { title: "Mr.", first: "John", last: "Doe" },
            { title: "Mrs.", first: "Jane", last: "Doe" },
        ],
        childs: [
            { title: "Ms.", first: "Jane", last: "Doe" },
            { title: "Mr.", first: "Joe", last: "Doe" },
        ],
    },
    {
        RoomType: {},
        Price: {},
        Messages: [],
        CancellationPolicyStatus: "",
        adults: [
            { title: "Mr.", first: "Johny", last: "Doe" },
            { title: "Mrs.", first: "Jane", last: "Doe" },
        ],
        childs: [
            { title: "Ms.", first: "Jane", last: "Doe" },
            { title: "Mr.", first: "Jui", last: "Doe" },
        ],
    },
];
const store = {};

const findDupe = (o, type) => {
    const key = [o.first, o.last].join();
    const tbl = (store[type] = store[type] || {});
    if (!tbl[key]) {
        tbl[key] = [o];
        return;
    }
    if (tbl[key].length === 1) {
        tbl[key][0].error = "Duplicate name, please update.";
    }
    o.error = "Duplicate name, please update.";
    tbl[key].push(o);
};
data.forEach((record) => {
    record.adults.forEach((adult) => findDupe(adult, "adults"));
    record.childs.forEach((child) => findDupe(child, "childs"));
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Edit: as requested - explanation of `findDupe` -

1. creates a "key" by combining first and lastname together
2. creates store[type] object if it doesn't exist
3. if the key made in 1 doesn't exist in the object made in 2, create the key as an array and store the current person in it - done
4. otherwise it's a duplicate - add it to the array in step 3
5. if it's the first duplicate, mark the first person in the array as a duplicate
6. mark this person as a duplicate

Comment: Regarding note: It came from my edit, my apologies

Comment: @RhettHarrison - you changed `childs` to `children` in the question? I'll remove my note then :p

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Looks like the question asker approved it and then made more edits

Comment: Indeed - I'll keep my code as `childs` :p - easy to fix as it only appears once in the code anyway :p

Comment: Grammatically, childs is wrong, but it felt easier to read with adults.

Comment: the property name is irrelevant :p

Comment: @JaromandaX could you please explain your "findDupe" function?

Comment: @SheehabMuhammad - added an explanation of  findDupe

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this, but this should suit your needs.
You'll need to loop over both of the arrays checking the names of each object.
Set the error for both `adult` and `child` if you come across a match.

Should also be worth noting that your parent array of these objects was not named (unless it is named props, I don't use Vue so I don't know if that is a convention or not) so you would have to loop through every object in the parent array to do this.

```
const namesArray = [];
// Loop over the adults array. Store the names and index to check against later
adults.forEach((adult, index) => {
  let fullName = adult.first + adult.last;
  namesArray.push({name: fullName, index: index});
}

// Loop over the child array
// If the name of a child is found in the namesArray, set the error for the child and the corresponding adult
children.forEach(child => {
  let fullName = child.first + child.last;
  namesArray.forEach(nameObject => {
    if(nameObject.name === fullName) {
      child.error = 'Duplicate name, please update.';
      adults[nameObject.index].error = 'Duplicate name, please update.';
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two objects (database) where first and last names will be stored, iterate your objects and check if first/last name exists in the database, if not, add them to the database:

```js
const arr = [
    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "John", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"}
    ],
    "childs": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Joe", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },

    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Johny", "last": "Doe",},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe",}
    ],
    "childs": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Jui", "last": "Doe"}
    ]
    },
];

function check(arr)
{

  //we'll store names for both adults and children in these objects
  const first = {},
        last = {};

  return arr.map(room =>
  {
    const checkDup = person =>
    {
      //check if this first/last name already exists in our database
      if (first[person.first] !== undefined && last[person.last] !== undefined)
      {
        //set error property in current person object
        person.error = "Duplicate name, please update.";
        //set error property in the original person object
        first[person.first].error = person.error;
      }
      else
      {
        //store names in the database
        first[person.first] = person;
        last[person.last] = person;
      }
      return person;
    }
    room.adults.forEach(checkDup);
    room.childs.forEach(checkDup);
    return room;
  });
}

console.log(check(arr));
/*
[
    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "John", "last": "Doe"},
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." }
    ],
    "childs": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." },
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Joe", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },

    {
    "RoomType":{  },
    "Price": {  }, 
    "Messages": [], 
    "CancellationPolicyStatus": "", 
    "adults": [
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Johny", "last": "Doe", },
        { "title": "Mrs.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." }
    ],
    "childs": [
        { "title": "Ms.", "first": "Jane", "last": "Doe", "error": "Duplicate name, please update." },
        { "title": "Mr.", "first": "Jui", "last": "Doe" }
    ]
    },
]
*/
```

> *not to be a grammar nazzy, but it's `children`, not `childs`*

Comment: why use `.map` if you ignore the result? you'd use `.forEach`, surely (`room.adults.map` for example, not where you DO return the result)

Comment: @JaromandaX good point, thanks.

Comment: Grammatically, childs is wrong, but it felt easier to read with adults.

Comment: What if we store both name part (Like ```[{first: "", last: ""}. ....]```)  in a single database array? 

It is a duplicate name only if both part matches with another names both parts

@vanowm

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question...If you store object in the array, you will have to iterate entire array for each person, which is slower than using object as database.